# In a Sql Bulk Insert statement, can we use relative path(files\a.txt) instead of absolute path(c:\abc\a.txt) or networked universal path (\\abc\a.txt)

Tags: sql, relative-path, bulkinsert

I wanted to insert data in a table from a text file where it is stored in csv format to a sql server table. For that, I am using bulk-insert statement. Now I need to specify the file name in "From" clause. I don't want to use networked locations or local locations over there. I want to upload my text file in the same directory as my executable file and give a relative path to it. Is it possible???

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. I just tried

```
SELECT BulkColumn
FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK'files\doesnotexist.txt',SINGLE_BLOB)x;
```

And looked at it in Process Monitor

And it was looking for `C:\WINDOWS\system32\files\doesnotexist.txt` so I think you would need to put in the full path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So can I use Sqlbulkcopy in c# to achieve my objectives then ???

Comment: Probably - but surely C# must have some command to retrieve the applications current directory that you can just append?